# Sql injection work but have allitle problem

Tags: html, sql, authentication, sql-injection, web-testing

username:admintest

password:' or 1=1#

(and it works perfectly)

But here is the problem

username:a-dmintest

password:' or 1=1#

(and it doesnt work)

when the username have a dash it don't work

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just dont have a user called "a-dmintest"

The dash is not a operator in SQL